# inotifywait reports that a to be created file is deleted before it's even created

Tags: linux, nginx, operating-system, system-administration

Hi I am having a situation where a file in a directory watched by inotifywait like so: `inotifywait -m -r -e delete -e created mydir`. I know that a process is going to write a file under mydir and I expect to see the file creation event reported by inotify. The problem is that the file is reported to be deleted and there is no sign of the create event of the same file before that. Of course I start watching the directory before I launch the process that creates the file. I am suspecting another cleanup process is deleting the file but still how is it possible that inotify prints that the file has been deleted and not file created before that. How can this possible?
Thanks

Comment: I am not aware of an `inotify` command line. Do you mean [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)? Are you sure that the file does not already exist and that the events are not indeed DELETE followed by CREATE? That is, is it possible that the process is first deleting the file and then recreating it?

Comment: What happened is that the process that creates the file, creates it in /tmp and than moves it to the directory being watched. add `-e moved_to` makes  thinks make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What happened is that the process that creates the file, creates it in /tmp and than moves it to the directory being watched. adding `-e moved_to` as option to `inotifywait` makes things make sense.